# Como puedo crear un campo array dinamico en django rest framework?

Tags: arraylist, djangorestframework, modelos

Estoy creando una aplicación donde necesito un array dinámico en uno de mis modelos, pero no encuentro documentación de como se puede hacer.
Específicamente lo que necesito es un arreglo de ImageField.
He buscado en google y en varios sitios, pero no encuentro nada sobre arreglos en django.
A lo mejor es que no se puede, alguien que me pueda ayudar, gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar que has intentado hasta ahora por favor? Las preguntas que dicen necesito esto sin haber buscado nada no son muy bien recibidas. ;)

Comment: Es q no se que intentar porq no encuentro información al respecto en google, estoy hasta pensando q no se puede.